# How to modify and paste values in a list

Tags: r, lapply, if-statement

I have a list:

```
my.list
[[1]]
[1] 1899 1899 1899 1899 1899 1899 1899 1899

[[2]]
[1] 86 86 86 86 86 86 86

[[3]]
 [1] 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97 97

[[4]]
[1] 3 3 3 3

[[5]]
 [1] 83 83 83 83 83 83 83 83 83 83

[[6]]
[1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

[[7]]
[1] 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10
```

`Dput:`

```
list(c(1899L, 1899L, 1899L, 1899L, 1899L, 1899L, 1899L, 1899L
), c(86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L, 86L), c(97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 
97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L, 97L), c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), c(83L, 83L, 
83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L, 83L), c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L),c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L ))
```

I would like to modify the values in each list element so I get:

```
my.listfinal
    [[1]]
    [1] 1899 1899 1899 1899 1899 1899 1899 1899

    [[2]]
    [1] 1886 1886 1886 1886 1886 1886 1886 

    [[3]]
     [1] 1897 1897 1897 1897 1897 1897 1897 1897 1897 1897 

    [[4]]
    [1] 1903 1903 1903 1903 

    [[5]]
     [1] 1883 1883 1883 1883 1883 1883 1883 1883 1883 1883 

    [[6]]
    [1] 1902 1902 1902 1902 1902 1902 1902 1902 

    [[7]]
    [1] 1910 1910 1910 1910 1910 1910 1910 1910
```

With other words, I would like to paste values with either 1901, 18, or leave them alone if `nchar==4`

I tried:

```
xxfinal=lapply(xxxm,function(x) { 

ifelse(unique(x) <10,paste0("190", x),ifelse(unique(x)==10,paste0("19",x),
ifelse(nchar(unique(x))==2 & unique(x)>10,paste0("18",x),x))) 

} 
)
```

But that gives me an `error`:

```
    Error in ifelse(unique(x) == 10, paste0("19", x), ifelse(nchar(unique(x) ==  : 
  unused argument (x)
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

That works:

```
my.listfinal=lapply(my.list,function(x) { 

as.numeric(ifelse(x<10,paste0("190", x),ifelse(x==10,paste0("19",x),
ifelse(nchar(x)==2 & x>10,paste0("18",x),x)))) 

} )
```

Thanks for you comments!

Comment: Insert `browser()` in your first line of the anonymous function passed to `lapply`. You can navigate through each iteration by `n` and `c`. You can inspect all objects and see if your code works and where it breaks. You can quite the debug mode with `Q` (see `?browser`).

Comment: I don't think you have closed your `nchar` at the right place

Comment: Also, I suggest you fold your code better to spot syntax errors.

Comment: @James thanks James! I corrected it, but i still does not work:/

Comment: as long as ifelse is already vectorized why you use unique? (I admit that I do not get you goal so maybe I'm completely off road here...)

Comment: @vodka Thanks! I just realized it too...It works now, see my edit. Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
lapply(my.list, function(x) x %% 1800 + 1800 + 100 * (x <= 10))
```

The result:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1899 1899 1899 1899 1899 1899 1899 1899

[[2]]
[1] 1886 1886 1886 1886 1886 1886 1886

[[3]]
 [1] 1897 1897 1897 1897 1897 1897 1897 1897 1897 1897

[[4]]
[1] 1903 1903 1903 1903

[[5]]
 [1] 1883 1883 1883 1883 1883 1883 1883 1883 1883 1883

[[6]]
[1] 1902 1902 1902 1902 1902 1902 1902 1902

[[7]]
[1] 1910 1910 1910 1910 1910 1910
```